# Griffith's Proof that a wave function will stay normalized is incorrect?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, schroedinger-equation, unitarity, normalization

In Griffith's book, Introduction to Quantum Mechanics, in the equation:
$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial t} \left| \Psi\right|^2 = \frac{i\hbar}{2m} \left( \Psi^* \frac{\partial^2 \Psi}{\partial x^2} -  \frac{\partial^2 \Psi^*}{\partial x^2} \Psi \right) \,,$$
he leaves out the term:
$$ -\frac{i}{\hbar} V \Psi \,.$$

This seems completely wrong to me. Why is he able to ignore the potential term? Is this proof even correct?  I've tried including the term, and the result I get says that the wave function shouldn't stay normalized? Any help as to what I'm missing?

Comment: The wavefunction stays normalized simply because the time evolution operator $\mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{i}Ht}$ is unitary. Without reading Griffiths, it's really not clear what this question is asking about, please include all relevent context in the question itself.

Comment: I'm unable to include more than 2 links? I have a link to the page with the proof though.

Comment: Here is the page with the proof: https://html1-f.scribdassets.com/88b4od9by83mmq6c/images/25-12a2b62b4c.jpg

Comment: Hint: Use the fact that the potential $V\in\mathbb{R}$ is real.

Comment: The potential term $V(x)$ is a function of position only in Griffith's argument (which he claims is usual for potential functions) and therefore does not come to play in the proof that the wave function remains normalized.

Comment: It seems pretty clear to me that you have neglected to make any attempts of your own to reproduce Griffiths' derivation, and therefore this question is off-topic.

Comment: We have the MathJax rendering engine running on the site, so it is preferable to render mathematics in that way to pasting pictures. I've done this one for you.

Comment: @rob: Minor thing: Should the textbook-erratum tag apply if there is not actually an error in the textbook here?

Comment: @Qmechanic Hmm, good question.  I think it should.  The question is "is there an error in this textbook?" I can't think of other useful tags whose applicability depends on the answer to the question. I could potentially be convinced otherwise.

Comment: Speaking in general (as opposed to this particular post), note that the Phys.SE community often overrides OP when it comes to choosing tags in order that the tags reflect the real (rather than any wrong initially perceived) issue. The [tag:textbook-erratum] tag is a meta tag in the sense that it doesn't narrow down the physics topic. However, it seems to have supporters. I get the impression that it was meant like a validation stamp that effectively says: _Yes, Phys.SE agrees: OP is right. There is an error._

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We know, from Schrodinger's equation, that

$$
\frac{d\psi}{dt}=\left(\frac{i\hbar}{2m}\frac{d^2}{dx^2}-\frac{i}{\hbar}V(x)\right)\psi
$$

Taking the conjugate tells us how $\psi^*$ evolves.

$$
\frac{d\psi^*}{dt}=\left(-\frac{i\hbar}{2m}\frac{d^2}{dx^2}+\frac{i}{\hbar}V(x)\right)\psi^*
$$

So let's calculate $\frac{d}{dt}|\psi|^2$.

\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dt}|\psi|^2&= \frac{d}{dt}\psi^*\psi\\
&=\psi^*\frac{d\psi}{dt}+\psi\frac{d\psi^*}{dt}\\
&=\psi^*\left(\frac{i\hbar}{2m}\frac{d^2\psi}{dx^2}-\frac{i}{\hbar}V(x)\psi\right)+\psi\left(-\frac{i\hbar}{2m}\frac{d^2\psi^*}{dx^2}+\frac{i}{\hbar}V(x)\psi^*\right)\\
&=\psi^*\frac{i\hbar}{2m}\frac{d^2\psi}{dx^2}-\psi\frac{i\hbar}{2m}\frac{d^2\psi^*}{dx^2}
\end{align}

So, Griffiths got it correct. The potential cancels from the final answer.

Comment: Thanks! That was such a silly mistake on my part. Maybe next time I should be a little more observant...